Different pin names in 0V7670 Camera Module
I am trying to follow this tutorial, SIMPLIFIED! How to Use OV7670 Camera with Arduino (other tutorials are also the same) and I noticed that my Camera module has different pin names, what do I do?
Here are images of my module:



How do the pin names differ? Please edit and list the differences. Have you looked for a tutorial that uses the same module as yours..?

The connections are exactly the same as the tutorial that you have linked to - it is only the pin labels that differ.
Tutorial           Module
-------            ------
SIOC               SCL
SIOD               SDA
VSYNC              VS
PCLK               PCLK
XCLK               MCLK
RESET              RST
PWDN               PWWN

